# MassTransit connecting before EF Core migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, masstransit, ef-core-6.0

I configure mass transit in `Startup.ConfigureServices` with:

```
services.AddMassTransit(cfg => {
    cfg.AddConsumers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);

    cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitMqCfg) => {
        rabbitMqCfg.Host(rabbitMqOptions.Host, rabbitMqOptions.VirtualHost,
            h => {
             h.Username(rabbitMqOptions.Username);
             h.Password(rabbitMqOptions.Password);
            });
    });
});
```

Registration is successfully done.

I need to check if there are migrations outstanding in `Startup.Configure`, and migrate if necessary with:

```
using var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()?.CreateScope();
var context = serviceScope?.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDbContext>();
if (context?.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any() ?? false)
    context?.Database.Migrate();
```

At this point, when `serviceScope?.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDbContext>();` is called, mass transit's singletons are instantiated and it automatically connects to rabbit-mq. The problem is that there are consumers that have messages in the queue and they use the database. The consumer throws an exception due to its usage of not-yet-migrated database.

The flow should be: Rabbit-Mq configuration -> Run migrations -> connect to rabbit-mq.

**The question is:** How to avoid the start when I resolve DbContext?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the absolute best way to handle migrations is using a hosted service and applying the migrations in the `StartAsync` method. Do not use a `BackgroundService`, as those are async and don't block startup.

For [example](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox/blob/master/src/Sample.Api/Program.cs#L48), the migration hosted service is added **BEFORE** any others, including the `AddMassTransit()` call.

Then, in the [hosted service](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox/blob/master/src/Sample.Api/RecreateDatabaseHostedService.cs) you can apply the migrations. Yes, I realize in this code I'm recreating the database, but the same concept applies.

This ensure that the migrations run before MassTransit starts, and before ASP.NET Core, etc. starts.